# How to use jinja tag inside jinja tag

Tags: python, django, jinja2

This is my code:

```
{% if {{post.author.profile.image.url}} is None %}
```

When I run this code I get an error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{post.author.profile.image.url}}' from '{{post.author.profile.image.url}}'
```

How to solve this? And how to use a template tag inside a template tag

Comment: Is it Jinja or Django ? While both look similar, they are different template engines... Also, `{{ something }}` is not a tag, it's a variable.

Comment: I'm sorry its django

Comment: Then abdusco's answer is the right one.

Comment: Remove `{{` and `}}`. The `{{ value }}` notation is only used when you want to display the value of a Python variable in HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Use the value of expression directly, you shouldn't wrap it inside braces:

```
{% if post.author.profile.image.url is None %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

abdusco's already answered the first part of your question ("how to solve this").

wrt/ the second part:

> how to use a template tag inside a template tag

The simple answer is: you can't, period. Why it's not possible becomes rather obvious once you understand how the template system works, and that would be mostly useless anyway (if you find yourself trying to use a tag within a tag then you're doing it wrong and there's a better way, really).

NB: when I say you can`t nest tags, I mean that you can't do this:

```
{% sometag arg={% some_other_tag %} %}
```

Now in your example, what you're trying to do is not "using a tag inside a tag", but using a *context variable* within a tag, and this is *of course* possible (else the template language would be rather hard to use), as shown in abdusco's answer. And you can also use filter expressions (apply a filter to a context variable) here, ie `{% mytag some.variable|upper %}`, at least if the template tag is correctly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The first question has already answered. Regarding to this one:

> And how to use a template tag inside a template tag

Short answer: you can't. Long answer: you can with help of the 'block assignment' tag ( http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#block-assignments ) :

```
{% set somevar %}
... any number of tags here {{ post.author.profile.image.url }} ...
{% endset %}
...
{% if somevar is None %} ... {% endif %}
```

You can also (since Jinja2 2.10) apply filter to the assignment:

```
{% set somevar | default('Empty') %}
... any number of tags here {{ post.author.profile.image.url }} ...
{% endset %}
```